# WCF, Part By Part Data Transfer

Tags: wcf

For example, consider around 10000 records are being sent from WCF service to the calling client. As per WCF we can set the response buffer size in the web.config file. I want to get the response part by part like 1000 records at a time. How can this be achieved without any changes in the web.config file?.. Need help in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: WCF architecture doesn't know what a "record" is , so you'll have to write the necessary code to provide this functionality. buffer size is unrelated (as long as it's large enough for your data to fit)

Comment: May be the term "record" used would have changed the scope of my question. Sorry for using it. If the data size is more than 65536 (which is the default value) bytes, then wcf creates an error. One solution is to update the maximumbuffersize value in the web.config of wcf service. But, my question is how to avoid config file changes and proceed with the data transfer even if the data size is more than the default data size supported by WCF.

Comment: I see, note that it is a completely different question and you should replace your original post

Comment: I think, the explanation provided in my previous comment relates to the question. It's just in detail. It would help me, if a solution is provided to the question (also considering the details added).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Large Data and Streaming (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx) for information about how to handle your situation.

> By default, WCF processes messages in buffered mode. This means that
>   the entire content of a message is present in memory before it is sent
>   or after it is received. While that is a good strategy for most
>   scenarios, and necessary for messaging features such as digital
>   signatures and reliable delivery, large messages could exhaust a
>   system's resources.
>
> The strategy to deal with large payloads is
>   streaming. While messages, especially those expressed in XML, are
>   commonly thought of as being relatively compact data packages, a
>   message might be multiple gigabytes in size and resemble a continuous
>   data stream more than a data package. When data is transferred in
>   streaming mode instead of buffered mode, the sender makes the contents
>   of the message body available to the recipient in the form of a stream
>   and the message infrastructure continuously forwards the data from
>   sender to receiver as it becomes available